# Linux On a Second Hard Drive

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bios, multi-boot

I want to install a second os (a Linux distro) to a second SSD on my computer. I know about installation and etc. but I a fear of something.

Once I've tried to install second OS on my computer and GRUB didn't get installed and also it damaged my current OS' (Windows) boot files.

I want this scenario: I have 2 SSD and 1 HDD installed on my computer. HDD is going to be common. First SSD has Windows now. I have UEFI right now and I want to keep it.

I am going to install a Linux distro to my second SSD. I want my computer to open still Windows as default. Only if I change the boot priority from my BIOS, then it should open Linux. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to disable any kind of common boot, is to disconnect the Windows
disk while installing Linux to the other disk.

After re-connecting the Windows disk, verify in the BIOS that it is still
the default boot disk.

This way, you may use Windows as before.
To boot from Linux, you could change the boot order in the BIOS,
or more easily use the Boot Menu key during the boot.

Comment: That wont work with EFI since you will then have two EFI system partitions and there needs to be only one, and the EFI firmware must be configured to know about both boot loaders in it.

Comment: @psusi: My understanding is that an EFI BIOS will search for the EFI partition on the boot disk, so two EFI partitions on two disks might work. Do you think that this is wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong.. There is no "boot disk" in EFI -- that's a BIOS thing.  The EFI firmware does not just search for any bootloader in any ESP it can find.  It has a list of what bootloaders are installed, and which one should be used by default.  This list is updated when you install a new OS ( by `efibootmgr` in Linux ).  Thus, you can't just take a hard drive that has an ESP from one computer and plug it in to another and have it boot, since the boot catalog doesn't know about the boot loader on that new drive.

Comment: @psusi: The EFI BIOS searches for bootloaders inside the EFI partition that it finds. I believe that it will search first on the boot disk for the EFI partition, which it recognizes by its partition id. Only if this fails will it look at the other disks. You are referring to what happens after it finds this partition, not to my scenario.

Comment: It does work this way, at least in my MSI X570 motherboard it does, I have two EFI partitions on two M.2 drives and when I boot I can select the One-Time Boot Menu and select a "drive" (or EFI partition perhaps) and switch between OSes that way. Both were installed while the other OSes drive was removed. And the system is definitely in EFI mode.

Comment: I believe that installing the new OS by unmounting the current one will work. By this way, I will be able to boot the OS I want by changing boot order of the hard drives?

Comment: @CanEkkazan: Yes, this should be the case. Also, by trying this method you will not be doing anything irreversible.

Comment: @harrymc, no, the boot catalog even specifies which disk on which the ESP is located.

Comment: @psusi: We have above a user testimony by acejavelin that it does work this way. Letting the poster test it on his BIOS is much better than arguing it here.

Comment: @acejavelin, That sounds like a removable media boot.  In order to boot from removable media for the first time to install an OS, there is a provision for a boot loader specifically named \BOOT\EFI\BOOTX64.EFI that the firmware will use when you ask it to boot from the removable media.  Normally such a file does not exist in the ESP of the hard disk, but if you have run the program boot repair, I believe it does copy grub to that removable name.

Comment: @harrymc, not quite.. he said that he can choose to boot from that drive on a one time basis... for it to happen by default, it has to be registered in the boot catalog.  On the other hand... if one boot loader is the default, but you disconnect the drive it is on, then it may fall back to the next entry, so if you just unplug Windows when installing Linux, then Linux will be the default, but if you unplug that drive, it may fall back to Windows without you having to explicitly ask for it at each boot.  So maybe that will do what the OP wants.

Comment: I can set one or another to boot first in the UEFI firmware... I do not have to use the one time boot menu each time.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are in EFI mode and also install Linux in EFI mode, then you will still be able to boot Windows either through grub, or by choosing the Windows boot loader in your EFI firmware.  You can use `efibootmgr` to change the default back to the Windows loader after installing Linux if you like.

Comment: This is exactly what the poster is looking to **avoid** - to not have Grub on his disk updated by the Linux installation. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @harrymc, he is looking to avoid having grub take over and not be able to get back to the Windows boot loader.  Like I said, simply use `efibootmgr` to switch it back to Windows before you reboot, and who cares if grub was the default for 5 seconds?  Also with EFI, you can always ask the firmware to use the Windows boot loader instead of grub.  This was not the case with bios, so could cause you some pain if you blew away your linux partition while grub was still in charge.